# Kotlin/Native error: Entry point can not be a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-native

When I use Kotlin Coroutines in a Kotlin/JVM project I can add the `suspend` keyword to the main entry of the program.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun main() {
  doWorld()
}

suspend fun doWorld() = coroutineScope {
  launch {
    delay(1000L)
    println("World!")
  }
  println("Hello")
}
```

[*Run example in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/LqQjpqF2j)

However, when I use the same code in a Kotlin Native project, I get an error at runtime

```
e: Entry point can not be a suspend function.
```

I have found [a YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52753/Native-Support-suspending-entrypoints) requesting `suspend fun main()` support in Kotlin Native.

Until the feature is available, what is the equivalent to `suspend fun main()` in Kotlin Native?

---

I'm using

- Kotlin/Native v1.7.22
- Kotlinx Coroutines 1.6.4

Answer (score 1):

try this code...

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        doWorld()
    }
}

suspend fun doWorld() = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello")
}
```

You need to call `doWorld()` method from anyother coroutine or have to make `suspend` function. The purpose is to change any thread to Main-thread.

Comment: Is there something better than runBlocking? It seems kind of hacky.

Comment: yes, you can use 'lifeCycleScope' (if you are in either activity or fragment), or start a Coroutine "CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { doWorld() }

Comment: "activity or fragment" leads me to believe that you're talking about Android which is Kotlin/JVM and not Kotlin/Native. Does Dispatchers.Main also exist for Kotlin/Native?